# Request list data of type json using AJAX to dynamically output in a bubble chart from chart.js

Tags: javascript, c#, sql

I have a data table containing data from a SQL database. I want to plot this data on a chart.js bubble chart. I have so far done the following:
 1. Queried the SQL database and retrieved the output into an objectList of type `BubbleData` which contains two properties:

```
 public string category { get; set; }
 public decimal score { get; set; }
```

2. Created a method in my web form to return the objectList

```cs
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<BubbleData> ReturnData()
{
    string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_ui_ExecView_Bubble", cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RunID", 1);
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    var dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    cn.Close();

    List<BubbleData> objectList = new List<BubbleData>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        objectList.Add(new BubbleData()
        {
            category = dr["Category"].ToString(),
                score = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Score"].ToString()) * 100
        });
     }

     return objectList;
}
```

3. Javascript file - WHERE I AM STUCK:

```js
$(function() {

    var popData = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "ExecView.aspx/ReturnData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var myData = data.d; 
            console.log(myData[0]);
        }
    });

    var popData = {
        datasets: [{
            label: ['Test'],
            data: [{
                x: 100,
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: 60,
                y: 30
            }, {
                x: 40,
                y: 60
            }, {
                x: 80,
                y: 80
            }, {
                x: 20,
                y: 30
            }, {
                x: 0,
                y: 10
            }],
        }]
    };

    var bubbleOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
    };

    var ctx5 = document.getElementById("bubble_chart").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx5, { type: 'bubble', data: popData, options: bubbleOptions });
});
```

In the javascript file I have the data e.g. myData[0] but how do I use it dynamically in the popData variable. The values hardcoded in data (popData) I want to replace with the values from the ajax request WebMethod.

Comment: My edit didn't seem to have worked, maybe i'll try again, but first i'll try to find an answer. To be clear, your request `$.ajax({...})` works, right? Another thing that it's not clear to me: with what rules you plot a BubbleData on the bubble chart? Score can be used as one axis, but the other?

Comment: Yep my Ajax request works! I can see in the console all the categories and scores! So X axis I want to plot the category and the y axis is the scores. So the bubbles should represent the score.

Comment: There can be multiple `BubbleData`  for a single category?

Comment: One score for one category

Comment: E.g Category “Blue” has a score of 30. So I want to have Blue on my X axis and plot 30 in the bubble against my y axis. Category “yellow” has a score of 20. So Yellow as my next point on my X axis. And 20 against my y axis

Comment: I'm not sure if you could have the category name as a label on the axis, but for that you can look into the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bubble.html#general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```js
$(function() {

    var bubbleData;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "ExecView.aspx/ReturnData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var bubbleDatas = data.d;
            bubbleData = new Array(bubbleDatas.length);

            for (i = 0; i < bubbleDatas.length; i++) {
                bubbleData[i] = {x: i, y:bubbleDatas[i].score};
            }
        }
    });

    var popData = {
        datasets: [{
            label: ['Test'],
            data: bubbleData
        }]
    };

    var bubbleOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
    };

    var ctx5 = document.getElementById("bubble_chart").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx5, { type: 'bubble', data: popData, options: bubbleOptions });
});
```

I did not test this code and i'm not a javascript expert, so take this as a suggestion rather than a sure answer.

I hope I was helpful

Comment: This helps - but i dont see any bubbles on the chart so im guessing its my axis min and max

Comment: Yeah, it was an error of mine, I've changed `popData[i] = {x: i, y:bubbleDatas[i].score};` to `bubbleData[i] = {x: i, y:bubbleDatas[i].score};`

Comment: Yup this works! Ok so now just need to figure out how to get the categories to show as labels. Thanks